# Suggested edit limit for low rep users

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Can limit of suggested edits **on the same question** be enforced, dropped, or atleast looked at?

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/posts/414608/revisions) is a more-than perfect example - I allowed this through once, but then it appeared again...

This may be good for low rep users, though it is a useful way to earn rep, particularly as they can't do much until you get above 50.

Comment: based on the number of mistakes left in that post after the edits were made, every single one of those edits should have been rejected.

Comment: they needed attention from the beginning I think. Just look at the time elapsed between each edit O_o

Comment: It could be a bot as well as far as I know ;)

Comment: They're accepted by the OP... Who also controls the accounts suggesting the edits.

Comment: @Oli ah, well, rather smart from him

Comment: @Oli - that was sort-of what was rather confusing, and why I did this question....

Comment: @Oli that's probably playing the system... as the edits are on the same word.